# Best practice of writing JS scripts with AJAX in Rails app? How to include URLs in script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to use a little bit of simple AJAX in my Rails application. The main problem I have is that inside a script I need to specify the URL where the request will go, which in most cases is a path to some Rails controller action. Anywhere else I'm advised not to write paths explicitly by hand (i.e. not do ugly stuff like `'/my_resources/' + resource_id`) but use helpers like `my_resource_path` instead.

But this approach doesn't work well with javascript, since these helpers don't work inside `assets/javascripts`. I can think of some ugly ways I can bypass the problem, currently I've implemented an extremely ugly workaround which is basically putting something like this inside my view:

```
<%= javascript_tag "onSubmitQuotePage('#{j escape_javascript(autocomplete_authors_url(''))}');"%>
```

But I can't imagine Rails developers didn't think of some prettier solution, some right way of doing AJAX.

Comment: that's the point of data-attrributes, a js action is linked to a dom element, this dom element should bear the relevant data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I like the way I do this so very happy to hear better ways of doing this.

But I either include the path in a data attribute on a relevant DOM element, or for some static routes I include a `<script>` block in the layout file that contains relevant paths.

```
<script>
(function() {
"use strict";
window.myapp || {};
window.myapp.new_order_path = '<%= new_order_path %>';
window.myapp.orders_path = '<%= orders_path %>';
...
}());
</script>
```

It's by no means a pretty solution, but the cases where I need a route in my JS are rather rare and that way I can then use `myapp.new_order_path` in my JS when I need it.

Comment: Data attributes make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents here: you can use Rails URI helpers to generate some sort of URI templates. E.g., if you have this route defined:

`edit_user   GET   /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit`

And you call it like `edit_user_path(':user_id:')`, it will return `/users/:user_id:/edit`. This way you can generate URI templates to be compiled by javascript. As @Tigraine said, you can include this in a data attribute of some top element, and use it from the client side.

It comes really in situations where you need to generate URIs for AJAX fetched resources: you just serve the resource id and let the javascript compile the URI from the template with a simple `string.replace(':user_id:', user_id)`.